# Joining queries with Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the table

**MOVIES_RATING:**

- `MovieID int`
- `MovieRating decimal`

I'd like to get 2 values using one query:

```
select COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[MOVIES_RATING]
where [dbo].[MOVIES_RATING].[MovieID] = 78
```

and

```
select SUM([dbo].[MOVIES_RATING].Rating)
FROM [dbo].[MOVIES_RATING]
where [dbo].[MOVIES_RATING].[MovieID] = 78
```

That's what I got in LINQ:

```
(from p in ef.MOVIES_RATING.Where(r => r.MovieID== movie_id)
let movieRates = ef.MOVIES_RATING.Where(r => r.MovieID == movie_id)
let count = movieRates.Count()
let averageUserRating = movieRates.Sum(c => c.MOVIES_RATING)/count
select new MovieRating {AverageUserRating = averageUserRating, VoteCount = count})
.Take(1);
```

Looks awful as well as SQL being generated:

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[MovieID] AS [MovieID], 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP 1
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[MovieID] AS [MovieID], 
    [GroupBy2].[A1] /  CAST( [GroupBy1].[A1] AS decimal(19,0)) AS [C2]
    FROM [dbo].[MOVIES_RATING] AS [Extent1]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[MOVIES_RATING] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[MovieID] = 78 ) AS [GroupBy1]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        SUM([Extent3].[Rating]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[MOVIES_RATING] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE [Extent3].[MovieID] = 78 ) AS [GroupBy2]
    WHERE [Extent1].[MovieID] = 78
)  AS [Limit1]
```

I'm not sure it is best solution, so any help is appreciated.

I know It can be done using stored procedure, but if its could be done using LINQ it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simple query:

```
var query = from m in context.Movies
            where m.Id == 78
            select new 
                {
                    Count = m.MovieRatings.Count(),
                    Sum = m.MovieRatings.Sum(mr => mr.Rating)
                };

var data = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

Moving average computation to your application code should reduce the SQL query complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
from r in ef.MOVIES_RATING
group r by r.MovieID into g
where g.Key == movie_id
select new
{
    Count = g.Count(),
    Sum = g.Sum(r => r.Rating)
}
```

(or perhaps filter first then group; it probably translates to the same SQL anyway)

Another approach, using `Aggregate`:

```
ef.MOVIES_RATING
    .Where(r => r.MovieID == movie_id)
    .Aggregate(
        new { Count = 0, Sum = 0 },
        (acc, r) => new { Count = acc.Count + 1, Sum = acc.Sum + r.Rating });
```

(not sure how it translates to SQL though)